# SQL Server without Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query `select sub_name from sub_table`, which gives me the result around 6-10 rows. Can any one suggest me how to convert( write sp ) these rows to columns for another table?

Comment: Check this: https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/

Comment: Please provide some more info: "for another table" means what? Do you want to create a new table basing on these columns? Do you want to match these columns to another already existing table?